# DataMapper one-to-many delete failing

Tags: ruby, associations, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

```
class Alpha
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,   Serial
  property :name, String
  has n, :betas
end

class Beta
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,   Serial
  property :name, String
  belongs_to :alpha
end

# Create an Alpha with two Betas
@alpha = Alpha.new(:name => 'A')
@alpha.betas << Beta.new(:name => 'B')
@alpha.betas << Beta.new(:name => 'C')
@alpha.save

puts @alpha.betas.inspect
puts "Destroyed? #{@alpha.betas.first.destroy}"
puts @alpha.betas.inspect
```

For some reason, DataMapper isn't deleting the associated Beta object.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

A complete example is in this gist https://gist.github.com/2219479

**EDIT**:

The answer is to reload the Alpha object after destroying the Beta

```
puts @alpha.betas.inspect
puts "Destroyed? #{@alpha.betas.first.destroy}"
puts @alpha.betas.reload
puts @alpha.betas.inspect
```

Comment: If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the answer from the edited question body in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> The answer is to reload the Alpha object after destroying the Beta
>
> ```
> puts @alpha.betas.inspect
> puts "Destroyed? #{@alpha.betas.first.destroy}"
> puts @alpha.betas.reload
> puts @alpha.betas.inspect
> ```

~ answer per [Craig552uk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352785/craig552uk)